# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/protocol/ProtocolSocketFactory

Tags: java

I am looking for a jar alternative for commons-httpclient-3.1.jar.

It contains a java class called ProtocolSocketFactory.

ProtocolSocketFactory class is not present in httpclient4 or httpclient5.

ProtocolSocketFactory particular class is referenced in opensaml-2.6.6.jar.

`DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();`

[image: Opensaml jar decompiled]

As you can see it is referencing ProtocolSocketFactory from commons-httpclient-3.1.jar.
[image]

Any way to fix this issue related to commons-httpclient-3.1.jar whereby, i can remove the jar and still make opensaml work with some alternative to commons-httpclient.

Comment: Hi, 
Did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Any workarounds?

Comment: i ended up building the jar from svn repo.